# ASP.NET MVC C# change code from accessing a mySQL database to a MSSQL database

Tags: c#

I have an application that I used to connect to a mySQL database.  I have installed the MySQL.Data package and I use this code to build my connection:

```
services.AddScoped<System.Data.IDbConnection>((s) =>
        {
            IDbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("databasename"));
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        });
```

This works fine as I am able to read/write data from the database.

Now, I need to have the same application access a MS SQL database.  The tables are all the same and the fields on each table are the same as well.  I am having a hard time finding what I should change my code to (or what package I should include).  When I remove the MySQL.Data package, the MySqlConnection function becomes invalid (as would be expected).

Any idea what package to include and what function to use to establish the connection?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

EDIT #1

I found an old stackoverflow post (I should have referenced it here but I closed the window) that talks about this very issue.  The suggestion was to add

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and then change the assignment code to

```
IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("databasename"));
```

I made these changes and now I get this error within the code:

[image]

Im at a loss as to how to resolve this.  I verified that my project is in framework .NET core 3.1

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags

Comment: use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: @MitchWheat - yes, the question is about switching from MySQL to MSSql

Comment: To resolve your 2nd problem you need to add the System.Data.SqlClient assembly to your project - usually done via a nuget package in .net core.

Comment: @PeteGO I must have manually typed in using System.Data.SqlClient.  It was light grey color.  I removed the line and then the intelitype informed me of an error on the assignment line.  The suggested resolution was to add using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.  That cleared up my assignment issue.  I'm getting other handshake errors now but at least the connection is being made.  Looks like I have to dive further in.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonathanSmall Did you add reference to the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient or System.Data.SqlClient nuget package?

Answer (score -3):

Not sure about size of your project and detailed requirements but I would suggest to use libraries like:

Entity Framework - no SQL knowledge needed, can connect to any Db technology, almost no code changes required when switching between Db providers

or

Dapper - fast lightweight also supports multiple Db providers but you need to write correct SQL commands yourself specific for each Db technology you use

Comment: using EF is like using a RegEx: now you have 2 problems!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat What do you mean by 2 problems?

Comment: Think of a popular web site that's consistently fast (SO for instance) and ask yourself if it uses EF or Dapper.....

Comment: @JanH - I have Dapper installed.  That's what I was using with mySQL.  I assume I can still use Dapper to actually send the sql commands to the database.  What I dont know (and havent been able to find on the internet) is the way to set up the variable conn.  With mySQL its defined as an IDBConnection and the assign makes use of the MySqlConnection function provided through mySQL.  There must be a corresponding command that will become available when I install some package for MQ SQL.  But I dont know what package that would be.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat you could ask why SO uses c# and not c++ when it is much faster? If you develop software where difficult db operations are not needed and data access is not bottleneck it is stupid to write every sql query manually when there are tools that can do it by calling one method...

Comment: @Jonathan Small can you use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection instead? Also one of your concerns should be that MySQL server and MS Sql server have different sql commands so you can't reuse everything just like that, that the reason why I recommended EF since it generates correct SQL commands based on Db it uses

Comment: @JanH: C++ is not in general faster than C#. That's a myth.  "If you develop software" - yes, I do. A lot of software....

Comment: @Mitch Wheat if you write c# unmanaged code that I strongly  believe you can achieve the same speed as c++ but if you write normal managed c# code with garbage collection, like 99.99% of all c# developers do, it must be slower since automatical memory management has its own cost (they might be cases where GC can make things faster but generally it makes things slower). If you don't like to compare C# to C++ that's fine :) just think for a second why big companies use python/TS - that's the same example... The question was how to make something work not how to make the fastest data access ever

Comment: The main reason why 'big companies' use TS over Python is strong typing not speed.

Comment: All very nice arguments but not directly relevant to the problem: OP needs the right client library

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I guess you still don't understand me :). I am huge fan of strong typed languages but big companies uses both Python and TS over C++ because it is faster to learn and develop simple application. That's same with EF, don't use EF if you need super super fast DB access (EF has caching out of the box so I could argue it can be even faster than direct sql/dapper in certain scenarios ;) ), but 90% of all C# developers don't need that the same way not all developers should learn C#/C/C++ or multiple SQL languages just because it's faster